# Javascript remove leading character(s) from form data

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript (and any programming for that matter) and I am looking for a way to take form data and remove leading character(s) from it and re-display them in a list.

For example:

aExample1

bExample2

cExample3

and re-display

Example1

Example2

Example3

Either on the fly or with a button.

(code from comment:

```
<html> 
    <textarea name="Text1" cols="20" rows="5">
        aExample1 bExample2 cExample3 
    </textarea> 
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</html>
```

)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a method like this:

```
 function cutFirst(txt) { return txt.substring(1) ;}
```

It takes a string, and returns all the letters but for the first.
You can play with it, and do something like:

```
 function cutSome(txt,start) { return txt.substring(start) ;}
```

This will remove the amount of letters that you pass in `start` (Note: it'll act funny if you don't pass the `start` though, since it'll be undefined, treated as `0`, and you'll get your original string back).

Even better, you can do:

```
 function cutSome(txt,start) { 
     return start ? txt.substring(start) 
                  : txt.substring(1) ;
}
```

Cutting out only the first letter if you don't pass the amount `start` argument.

---

As for comments, You could do this (i've added an ID , but you can get it by name as well":

```
<textarea name="Text1" cols="20" rows="5" ID="TextID">
    aExample1 bExample2 cExample3 
</textarea> 
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="trimText();"/>
```

and have this in you JavaScript:

```
function trimText() {
    var tmpArray= document.getElementById("TextID").value.trim().split(" ");
    var returnArray = [];
    var len = tmpArray.length;
    while (len--) {
        returnArray[len] = tmpArray[len].substring(1);
    }
    document.getElementById("TextID").value = returnArray.join(" ");
}
```

This will fetch your input, split into words, remove first letter, put back into a string, and change the text area text to that value :)

Comment: `txt.substring(start || 1)` would be cleaner if you dont care about 0

Comment: @megawac true ...true... +1 to you good ser.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. How would that be applied to the form data itself?

Comment: Well, that depends on how and where you're using it. You're not very clear about that in your question, and have no code, so it'll be hard to say.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. How would the script be implemented in the following example so when the user presses Submit it will remove the leading character for each line.
<html>
<textarea name="Text1" cols="20" rows="5">
aExample1
bExample2
cExample3
</textarea>
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</html>

Comment: @megawac I would argue for `start || 0` instead. This way the function is more general and predictable instead of defaulting to the removal of the first character. Also @Noctis, instead of wrapping `substring`, why not just use `substring`?

Comment: @Peter even better ... you have a point about the wrapping of the substring, but I'm usually doing more things in a method, so I guess it's the force of habit :)